# I want to have a fade effect on the script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wrote the script code.

I want to have a fade effect on the script.

How can I add a fade effect to this code?

please help..!

※I used a translator because I couldn't speak English. That is why my words may not be natural. Please understand.

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const activeOn = document.querySelector('#wrap');

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  activeOn.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

#wrap.active {
  display: block;
}

.contents {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#none">Click</a>

<div id="wrap">
  <div class="contents">
    Active Contents!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do the fade effect is using CSS transition.

One thing to note is CSS transitions don't work if you're toggling `display: block` and `display: none`, so you need to instead consider using `visibility` or `opacity` attributes.

Here's the working code:

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const activeOn = document.querySelector('#wrap');

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  activeOn.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#wrap {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
  height: 0; /* add this if you want it to take no space */
}

#wrap.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.contents {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#none">Click</a>

<div id="wrap">
  <div class="contents">
    Active Contents!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't think to use the opacity of css, and I tried to modify only the script code unnecessarily.
Thanks for making it easy to fix:)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `opacity` instead of `display`, like this:

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const activeOn = document.querySelector('#wrap');

toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    activeOn.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#wrap {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s; 
}

#wrap.active { 
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.contents {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#none">Click</a>

    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="contents">
            Active Contents!
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I didn't think to use the opacity of css, and I tried to modify only the script code unnecessarily.
Thanks for making it easy to fix:)